# official way to implement repository pattern into laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to know if it is good to use repository pattern in laravel or not. I read in somewhere that it's a DRY to use repository pattern because We use Eloquent in laravel and some other places like here

```
https://www.dunebook.com/brief-overview-of-design-patterns-used-in-laravel/3
```

so here is example of the above link :

```
interface UserRepository {


   public function all(); 
}
```

and the repo

```
use User;

class EloquentUserRepository implements UserRepository {

  public function all()
  {
    return User::all();
  }
```

and finally in controller :

```
User::find($id)
```

gives advice to use repository pattern and as I feel it's a kind of duplication in code . any help or source to get hint from?

Answer (score 0):

The repository pattern is doing something like:

- Hey interface! Give me all users (UsersRepository all)
- Hey Eloquent! Give me all users. (EloquentUsersRepository)

The part when you call for `User::find($id)` in your controller (I'm assuming is a mistake, since you wrote an `all` function on your repository is that what you should be using on your controller).

I've done some implementations of the repository pattern on Laravel and I've done it that way. The only thing you did not mention, but I guess you are doing as well is binding the interface to the EloquentUserRepository implementation using the Laravel ioc container, so everytime you ask for an instance of the interface it gets automatically resolved with an eloquent implementation instance.

It actually seems that you are repeating code but you are not, sometimes the repository pattern may not be suitable to your needs today so it seems you are just adding unnecesary complexity to the code. In our case we started writing an application using the repository pattern but didn't take advantage of it so we were just writing that unnecessary layer of complexity, when we realised we got rid of it and decided to use the models directly, some time after we started to need it again under certain circumstances so we implemented it again, as I said, it all depends on your needs at the time.

The most mentioned need for using this pattern is the possibility of changing of ORM easily, but in our case that never happened and honestly, doesn't seem to be happening. But one useful use case for having a repository would be the following: Let's suppose you an algorithm that for example, calculates the number of users having a username starting with the letter *a*, ideally you would not implement this on your framework project, but on a separate one, that way you can test it independently and reuse it. In short words, to count the usernames that start with *a* you don't actually need to know that your project is a Laravel one, a Codeigniter one, has Eloquent, Redis, or the users written in an Excel document, all you need to know is that it can provide you with all users, and that's why having a users repository interface is useful, your algorithm would just say *I need all users* and would not care about anything else.